# What's the difference between | vs. ||

Tags: ruby

I know this means or

```
 true || false
 => true
```

but the other day I accidentally used one vertical line instead and found that my code still worked.

```
true | false
=> true

false | false
=> false
```

So what is the difference between these | and ||?  Are they equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

| is the bitwise OR operator.
|| is the logical OR operator.

See here for explanations on both operators: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm.

Comment: Is it correct to say that | includes all the functionality of || plus it can handle bits as well?

Comment: @User314159 No - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`|` is the *bitwise OR* operator.  `||` is *logical OR*.

The main difference, when used as you demonstrated, is that `||` will short circuit, and not evalute the right hand side when the left hand side is true.  Using `|` will always evaluate both sides.

In this case, that likely doesn't matter - but if the two sides of the operator were expensive to compute, `||` would be more efficient.

As such, it's almost always better to use `||` when doing a logical test (ie: "if"), as this will express your intent more clearly, as well as potentially be more efficient.

The `|` operator is more useful when doing bit manipulations directly, and really typically only suited for those scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

`||` is logical OR operator.

---

`a | b` is like `a.|(b)`. So its meaning depends on the class of `a`.

It does bitwise OR if the first operand is `Fixnum`: [`Fixnum#|`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-7C).

Logical OR if the first operand is `true` or `false`: [`TrueClass#|`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/TrueClass.html#method-i-7C), [`FalseClass#|`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/FalseClass.html#method-i-7C); `||`, `|` yield same result if both operands are `true`/`false`.

[`NilClass#|`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/NilClass.html#method-i-7C), ...

---

Another difference:  `||` short-circuit, while `|` does not.

For example:

```
def f1
  p 'f1 called'
  true
end

def f2
  p 'f2 called'
  true
end

p(f1 || f2)
# => "f1 called"
#    true

p(f1 | f2)
# => "f1 called"
#    "f2 called"
#    true
```

---

```
1 || 2 # return first non-false/nil value.
# => 1
nil || 1
# => 1

1 | 2 # 0b01 | 0b10 => 0b11 = 3
# => 3
>> nil | 1
# => true
1 | nil
# => TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
#           from (irb):7:in `|'
#           from (irb):7
#           from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```